# How to Access database files without Access Database Engine

Tags: c#, c++, database, 64-bit

I'm currently using access database engine 2010 (AccessRuntime 2013) to open and query various database files, .xls, .xlsx, .accessdb, .xml, .txt/csv/tab, .mdb, .dbf, etc...

But now I need to build a x64 application to do the same. However this creates a problem, on x64 PC's that still run Ms Office x86 or have other applications that use the x86 Access Database engine 2010.

The Access x64 runtime wont install next to the x86 version (you can force Access Database engine 2010 with /passive but this damages the x86 version and stops some applications to work at all (including old versions of my own software).
I've read a tone of topics about this issue, but never a solution.

I'm searching for an alternative to the Microsoft access database engine/runtime that allowes me to query various database files in C# or C++

Does anyone have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: If you are ok with changing your database you could export your access data to xml file then use vistaDB as you database program and import it then then you can write you application to use that database.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at sqlite as an alternative to the Access DB.

Comment: I have no control over what kind of source databases are used. And the end user does not always have the tools to convert their databases, nor is it practical. I'm searching for something as flexible as AccessDatabaseEngine but that does not conflict with other (x86/x64) applications.

Comment: Can you just continue to use the Access Runtime x86 engine, which runs on x86 or x64? What role does the x64 app you need to build play?

Comment: I wish we could, when our app is build for x64 (wich we do for various reasons) it requires the x64 Access Runtime. Installing that damages the x86 Access runtime installations 9 times out of 10 that might already be installed and used by other applications.
And thats something I wish to avoid, hence my search for an alternative way to be able to read & write many kinds of databases without using the access runtime.

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem? I am struggling with exact the same.

Comment: Sorry Egse, I did not find a proper solution or alternative. In the end I used  the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe with the /passive parameter. and that enables both x86 and x64 to be installed on 95% of the PC's the other 5% you probably have to convince to move their office to 64bit.